# "Restore failed" for Rider's Template Project

Tags: rider

I have a problem with my brand new instance of JetBrains Rider. After downloading it and creating the template project "ASP .NET Web Application" I get the following error message when trying to download NuGet packages:

```
Restore failed 
Restore failed for 14 packages in 1 project
```

The log is

```
[Notification][Restore] Restore failed
Restore failed for 14 packages in 1 project
```

The *packages/* folder does not exist.

I installed a couple of other programms (like the .NET Framework and even Visual Studio), I downloaded the nuget.exe and put it in the PATH environment variable. I moved the project around the hard drive because maybe Rider needs special permissions and even created the folder. Nothing helped so far.

When I type `nuget restore` manually, I get the following essage:

```
nuget : Errors in packages.config projects
At line:1 char:1
+ nuget restore
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Errors in packages.config projects:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
    Unable to find version '3.5.0.2' of package 'Antlr'.
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'Antlr.3.5.0.2' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
    Unable to find version '1.17.0' of package 'jQuery.Validation'.
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'jQuery.Validation.1.17.0' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
    Unable to find version '3.3.1' of package 'jQuery'.
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'jQuery.3.3.1' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
    Unable to find version '3.4.1' of package 'bootstrap'.
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'bootstrap.3.4.1' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
    Unable to find version '1.1.3' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization'.
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
    Unable to find version '5.2.7' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc'.
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.7' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
    Unable to find version '3.2.7' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor'.
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.2.7' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
    Unable to find version '3.2.7' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages'.
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.7' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
    Unable to find version '2.8.3' of package 'Modernizr'.
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'Modernizr.2.8.3' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
    Unable to find version '1.0.0' of package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure'.
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
    Unable to find version '1.6.0' of package 'WebGrease'.
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'WebGrease.1.6.0' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
    Unable to find version '3.2.11' of package 'Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation'.
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation.3.2.11' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
    Unable to find version '2.0.0' of package 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform'.
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.0' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
    Unable to find version '11.0.1' of package 'Newtonsoft.Json'.
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.1' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
```

How can I fix this error message and download NuGet packages in Rider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems downloading the *nuget.exe* and putting it in the PATH environment variable was correct. Additional, I had to add this to *C:\Users<username>\AppData\NuGet\NuGet.config*:

```xml
<configuration>
  <!-- stuff -->
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <!-- other stuff -->
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Then I called `nuget restore` and the 14 packages were successfully downloaded.  I haven't found a manual detailing this steps yet, so I'm not sure if more is missing.

Comment: After a clean Windows 11 install, Jetbrains Rider IDE was unable to restore NuGet packages. Your comment solved this issue. Thank you.